# Codeigniter phpexcel where clause

Tags: codeigniter, phpexcel

I have a program that will print mysql table to excel using phpexcel. At first its' ok when there's no condition was put but when I added the where clause in the query, the output returns blank. I need to print a report by its specific date. This is my controller query:

```
$str = @date('Y-m-d',@strtotime($this->input->post('q')));

    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('purchaseorders');
    $this->db->where('DateMade',$str); // if I remove this the excel file have contents.
    $rs = $this->db->get();
```

By the way the date that I am passing was from the date of the records that it was made.

I changed my view submission to jquery:

```
$('#btnprint').click(function(){
var datemade = $('#datemade').val();
console.log(datemade);
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url: "<?php echo site_url('wip/excel/');?>",
    data: {q:datemade},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
    },
});
});
```

and I put in the console log the data to see if it pass the parameters to the controller but what I am receiving is this:

[image]

Comment: Have you checked that the database query is returning any records?

Comment: Yes it does but without the where clause....

Comment: I tried also to put my query code on model page and call it controller, it works when the where clause is not present but when I added it the excel file returns empty....

Comment: So is $str a valid date?

Comment: Yes I used console log to check if it is and I converted it to mysql date format before passing the value to query.

Comment: console log is client side (in the browser); PHP runs server side..... how are you checking it in PHP?

Comment: I fix the error in console log by changing foreach($rs->result() as $val) to foreach($rs->result_array() as $val) but it does not create any excel file instead I receive this in console log.... See image posted....

Comment: If you send a file to the browser (with appropriate headings) then that must be the only thing that you send to the browser in response to that request..... from the image, it looks like your console log is filled with the binary stream from the excel file

Comment: However, if you're doing this via an Ajax call, then the success function needs to handle the response, because the browser only knows that it's receiving a stream of data, not what to do with that data

Comment: But based on your PHP and your jquery, `datemade` !== `DateMade`

Comment: datemade is the id of the datepicker that i have.....

Comment: Your Ajax request is using `datemade`, your PHP is using `DateMade`..... `datemade` !== `DateMade`

Comment: sorry but the id of datepicker is datemade and it's value is passed to query via ajax request. The DateMade is the a field in my table and if I reconstruct my query it will be SELECT * FROM purchaseorders WHERE DateMade = datemade.datepicker... Hope it is clear to you. Also I removed already my jquery so it's working ok now...

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution from this post [PHPExcel creates 'unreadable content'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15191199/phpexcel-creates-unreadable-content) and I remove also my jquery submission...