# PHPExcel export missing rows

Tags: php, excel, header

When i'm trying to export to excel the last part of the spreadsheet is missing. In the website i can get 5003 records but when i try to export to excel i only get 3700 rows(records). So the last part does not display. Im using the following headers to download the page as excel and call the page through ajax.

```
header("Pragma: public");   
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate"); // HTTP/1.1
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Cache-Control: maxage=3600"); //Adjust maxage appropriately
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$title.".xls\"");
header("Content-transfer-encoding: binary");
```

EDIT: 
im using the following code

```
$sql = "select * from transactions";
$rs  = $cn->Execute($sql);
while(!$rs->EOF){
   echo "<tr><td>".$rs->fields['transid'];."</td></tr>";
   //other fields here
   $rs->MoveNext();
}
//even if i put something here it will not be displayed.
echo "<tr><td>something here</td></tr>";
```

This should output an excel file with the display of all the transactions the total transactions is 5003

Comment: Are there any errors posted to your error log?

Comment: Try to dump your "Excel" data into your website (so print it within your html), and see if you really have the exact amount of rows there. If not, not ajax/headers are the problem. [Most times it's the other way round ... HTML < CSV when having memory issues]

Comment: Tried this answer here(?): header("Content-length: " . strlen($document));   //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10630789/excel-download-stuck-188kb?rq=1

Comment: Seeing the code where you're reading the database and generating your Excel file is more likely to identify the cause of the problem than simply seeing the headers that you send

Comment: I displayed the total number of rows its 5003 i even displayed this count in the excel. I also tried to echo a string to the bottom of the excel document and it did not appear even if it is outside the loop of rows

Comment: SHOW US THE CODE.... otherwise we can't help.... we don't even know if you're creating a proper BIFF-format .xls file (and if so, what library you're using), or simply creating an html or a csv and giving it a .xls extension

Comment: @djot i tried that code. It enlarges the file size but the content is still at 3600+ it never goes up that limit currently in our php.ini memory_limit is at 128M does that affect the file download?

Comment: So you're creating HTML rather than an Excel file, and only writing a single value from each record: why not simply write a plain text file? Check for timeouts in your logs